# Insert certain string after and before other strings in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed

So, I am trying to insert `b.b00 ---` after `modules=` and before `jumpstart.gz` in a file on Linux, but can't seem to figure out how to actually do it. I did look at other answers in the forum and apparently none of them have any effects.
My file name is boot.cfg and its content is as follows:

```
bootstate=0
timeout=5
kernelopt=runweasel
modules=jumstart.gz --- useropts.gz --- features.gz --- qeden.v00 ---tpm.v00
build=3.322.2
updated=0
```

What I am looking for is as follows:

```
bootstate=0
timeout=5
kernelopt=runweasel
modules=b.b00 --- jumstart.gz --- useropts.gz --- features.gz --- qeden.v00 ---tpm.v00
build=3.322.2
updated=0
```

So, basically add `b.b00 ---` after `modules` and before `jumpstart.gz`.

Some commands I tried were:

```
sed -i '/\[modules=\]/a b.b00 ---' boot.cfg
sed -i '/^jumpstart.gz.*/i b.b00 ---' boot.cfg
```

None of these commands seem to have any effect on the file. Could anyone please point me in the right direction. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you really only need to insert `b.b00 ---`  after `modules=` and doing so will already ensure that it comes before `jumstart.gz`. So, you were almost there, but for some reason you added extra `[` and `]` to your `sed` command and, since those characters don't appear in the file, that's why the command did nothing. Try this instead:

```
sed 's/modules=/modules=b.b00 --- /' grub.cfg
```

Once you've confirmed that works as expected, add the `-i` to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i 's/modules=/modules=b.b00 --- /' grub.cfg
```

If you only want to do this on lines matching `modules=` *and* containing `jumpstart.gz`, try this:

```
sed '/jumstart.gz/s/modules=/modules=b.b00 --- /' grub.cfg
```

And, again, to make it edit the file, use `-i`:

```
sed -i '/jumstart.gz/s/modules=/modules=b.b00 --- /' grub.cfg
```

Comment: Solved it! Thank you for the clear explanation as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you use this sentence it should work:

```
sed -i 's/modules=/modules=b.b00 --- /g' boot.cfg
```

**modules=** would be replaced with **modules=b.b00 ---** keeping the rest of the content in the same way